# component is not receiving updated state reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this Paypal buttons that are supposed to get amount to capture from the state.

```
state = {
    amount: 0,
  };
```

The state changes perfectly but the amount in the buttons remain the same i.e amount as `0`

```
componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.state.amount)
      let amount=this.state.amount;
      paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  amount: {
                    value: amount,
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          },
          onError: function(err){
            console.log(err)
          }
        })
        .render("#paypal");
    }
  }
```

I tried putting the buttons in `componentDidUpdate` but this just renders the buttons repeatedly everytime the state changes

```
    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log(this.state.amount)
paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  amount: {
                    value: amount,
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          },
          onError: function(err){
            console.log(err)
          }
        })
        .render("#paypal");

      }
```

I get the Paypal buttons are being rendered when the component is mounted but how will the buttons receive the updated value from state

Comment: could you include the full code of the component? what does that .render function of the paypal library?

Comment: You instantiate the PayPal buttons on mount, perfect.  But you should probably also update those PayPal functions on every state change.  Maybe you could redefine the PayPal stuff on each update(?) Look into react lifecycle methods to figure out how to do that.  ComponentWillReceive props might be the method but I’m on mobile and can’t remember exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `amount` declared in `componentDidMount` is restricted to the `scope of the componentDidMount method` and will not update with future changes to state

You can instead use the **reference of amount from state directly after binding the createOrder function**

```
componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.state.amount)
      paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: (data, actions) =>  { // Implemented as arrow for binding
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  amount: {
                    value: this.state.amount, // Will take the value from state instead of closure
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          },
          onError: function(err){
            console.log(err)
          }
        })
        .render("#paypal");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and the client throws an error that 'Error: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined'

Comment: Please convert createOrder to an arrow function as shown. This is required for binding `this` to class component

Comment: oh yeah had not noticed that (the new arrow function). Now it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
...
amount: {
  value: this.state.amount
},
...
```